# Дано два массива! Удалить с первого массива все элементы которые повторяются во втором!

Tags: javascript, массивы

Имеется 2 массива arr1 = [3, 4, 5] и arr2 = [3, 3, 20, 5].
Должен получиться arr3 = [4].

решение

```js
function arrayDiff(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1.length === 0 || arr2.length === 0) {
    return arr1;
  }
  const updatedArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    let flag = false;

    for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
      if (arr1[i] !== arr2[j]) {
        flag = true;
      }
    }

    if (flag) {
      updatedArray.push(arr1[i]);
      flag = false;
    }
  }
  return updatedArray;
}


console.log(arrayDiff([3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 20, 5]));
```

не могу понять что не так?!

Comment: **ИЗ** массива, годдэмит!

Comment: `function arrayDiff(arr1, arr2) {return arr1.filter(item => !arr2.includes(item))}`

Comment: А что не так? Что ожидается? Что получается? Посмотри внимательно на два массива, которые ты передаёшь в функцию.

Comment: То что передаю это просто я экспериментировал, там должен [] такой получиться но не получался. Глядя на ваше решение понимаю что ещё курить и курить! коротко и просто!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function arrayDiff(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1.length === 0 || arr2.length === 0) {
    return arr1;
  }
  const updatedArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    let found = false;

    for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
      if (arr1[i] === arr2[j]) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!found) {
      updatedArray.push(arr1[i]);
    }
  }
  return updatedArray;
}


console.log(arrayDiff([3, 4, 5], [3, 3, 20, 5]));
```

Comment: Бщльшое спасибо!